# Is there a way I can block access to my website by country?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to block access to my web site from some countries. The reason is that I suspect they are stealing the information from the site and copying for their own sites.

Is there a way I can block access from certain countries or even better redirect users accessing my site from these countries to a very plain web page that makes it look like the site is under construction.

Note that my site uses MVC3. I am looking for a .net solution or some IIS solution if that's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could setup the free [GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) database at yours and check each IP address (HTTP remote address of the visitor) against it and then decide what to do.

Another way would be to reverse-lookup the IP addresses, but then again, which country is a visitor with a hostname ending in `.net` from?

Finally, be aware that there are free proxy servers out there, so if someone really wants to fake his "country", he easily can do.

Comment: Yep. Checkout `Tor`. If anyone want to steel your content, they will probably succeed if they are clever enough.